# Approximate this big number using a binomial

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, cards

Mr. Magico is a greater believer in this number:

> $$2^{50}=1,125,899,906,842,624‬$$

He also like to play cards, although he isn't fussy about the size of his deck, and nor does he care how many cards he pulls.

He wishes to find $n,k$ such that:

> $$\binom{n}{k}\approx 2^{50}$$

and wants $n$ as small as possible, but also a very small error margin. $2^{50}$ cards gives $100\%$ accuracy, but is a very large pack of cards, probably too large for even Mr. Magico to carry around in his pocket!

With this in mind, we shall impose an upper limit of $n\le500$, although $n\le100$ would be better for Mr. Magico's posture!

> **What is Mr. Magico's ideal pack of cards, and how many cards should he pull?**

For a start $\dbinom{78}{14}=1,023,729,916,348,425$, an error of $\sim0.909$.

Comment: Clearly he should use a pack of $2^{50}$ cards and pull exactly one of them. More seriously, would you like to be a bit more precise about how you want the tradeoff between accuracy and feasibility to be made? And how do you feel about computer searches?

Comment: Computer searches are fine, I've tried by hand and it's painful!

Comment: Why is it "cIosed"?

Answer (score 5):

Choosing

> 16 cards from a deck of 67

gets to within about

> 0.2%

of the desired answer. I think this is best possible with <= 100 cards.

Found with the help of a computer, but purely as an aid to calculation. My approach was to

> follow the "boundary" near to the number wanted, increasing or decreasing $k$ and then adjusting $n$ to get as near as possible. I had to try about 30 values.

[EDITED to add:]

Out of curiosity, I also ran a more automated search for the larger bound of n=500 mentioned in the OP. For this,

> choosing 8 cards from 290 yields an error of about 0.03%.

The automated search also confirmed that the answer above is best for a maximum of 100 cards.

Comment: Checked all solutions for n<=500 in R, and your (290,8) is optimal (and naturally (290,282) is as well).

Comment: Checking all smaller values of k shows that the next best ones are (2671,5), (12824,4), (189041,3), (47453133,2), and finally ($2^{50}$,1).

Answer (score 3):

Generalizing my comment on Gareth's solution, we can
arrange Pascal's triangle as a right triangular array and ignore the right half ($n < 2k$) to obtain something like this:

```
1
1
1  2
1  3
1  4  6
...
```

We then, for *any* $N$,

> notice that all columns are strictly increasing, with minimal values equal to the [central binomial coefficients](http://oeis.org/A000984).
> This immediately produces an upper bound on $k$: the greatest value $m$ such that $\binom{2m}{m} \leq N$.
> We can then iterate down the remaining values of $k$, finding the values $n$ such that $\binom{n}{k}$ is closest to $N$ - these $n$ will also be increasing - and checking each one's relative error.
>  [This Python code](https://repl.it/@iamnotachuckste/Binomial-Approximation) does this fairly well, yielding the successive approximations $\binom{53}{26}, \binom{54}{23}, \binom{67}{16}, \binom{290}{8}, \binom{12823}{4}, \binom{189040}{3}, \binom{47453133}{2}, \binom{2^{50}}{1}$.

Comment: (of course, I should probably convert real roots to integer solutions in a manner more rigorous than rounding, but puzzles are more about method ;))

Answer (score 0):

Gareth has found the optimal solutions, but here is an R script if anyone wants to mess around with the upper bounds for n, just change the value of the variable"UpperBound".

```
require(pracma)

UpperBound<-500

n<-rep(1:UpperBound,each=UpperBound)
k<-rep(1:UpperBound,times=UpperBound)

data<-as.data.frame(cbind(n,k))
colnames(data)<-c("n","k")

data<-data[data$k<=data$n,]

for(i in 1:length(data$n)){
data$combin[i]<-nchoosek(data$n[i],data$k[i])
}
data$check<-2^50
data$diff<-data$combin-data$check

data$diff<-abs(data$diff)
data[data$diff==min(data$diff),]
```